# Asp.Net Core 2 endpoint being hit twice

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem: My endpoint in asp.net core 2 controller is being hit twice from my angular 4 client side JS.

Component HTML:

```
<h1>Login To Spotify</h1>

<button type="button" (click)="loginToSpotify()">Boop</button>
<p>{{_logger}}</p>
```

loginToSpotify will redirect the current page to itself with 2 parameters in the URL query string, code and state which is used by my next HTTP post request below.

Component method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.checkPostBack(this._router.url);
}

private checkPostBack(url: string) {
    let urlTree: UrlTree = this._router.parseUrl(url);

    this._spotifyRedirect = {
        code: urlTree.queryParamMap.get('code'),
        state: urlTree.queryParamMap.get('state')
    };

    if (this._spotifyRedirect.code === null && this._spotifyRedirect.state === null) {
        this._logger = "No code or state provided!";
        return;
    }

    let spotifyAccessTokenResponse: SpotifyAccessTokenResponse;

    this._spotifyService.getAccountAccessToken('example', this._spotifyRedirect.code, 'http://localhost:52028/spotifytoyoutube')
        .subscribe(result => {
            this._logger = "Logged into spotify successfully! ";
            spotifyAccessTokenResponse = result;
        }, error => {
            this._logger = "Error: " + error;
        });
}
```

Service method:

```
getAccountAccessToken(grantType: string | null, code: string | null, redirectUri: string) : Observable<SpotifyAccessTokenResponse> {
    let queryEncoder: QueryEncoder = new QueryEncoder();

    let spotifyAccessTokenRequest: SpotifyAccessTokenRequest = {
        grant_type: grantType,
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: queryEncoder.encodeValue(redirectUri)
    }

    return this.http
        .post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Spotify/AccessToken', spotifyAccessTokenRequest)
        .map(result => {
            return <SpotifyAccessTokenResponse>result.json();
        })
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .share();
}
```

When I breakpoint my asp.net controller endpoint its getting hit twice and there are no other references to this end point in my application. Am I doing something wrong in angular? When checking the web page via Fiddler it is only firing one HTTP Post to my end point, but its getting hit twice by the breakpoint. Adding some console.log statements only get run once as well in the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your HTML template

Comment: @Sajeetharan its very simple and this code only gets executed when the page is redirected. I will update the post with the ngOnInit